# How to store Date object in App Engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to store `java.util.Date` in AppEngine. Storing and retrieving `Date` object seems simple.

Do storing as `Date.getTime()` `long` data type will occupy less space?

Even if it a slight improvement in memory saving I will prefer that.

Comment: What is exactly the reason why you would like to do that? If it is a question of space saving, I am not sure you should really have do that, with regards to the price of storage. If it is a question of facilitating a specific sorting then you could indeed store the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. You coud also store the date a YYYYMMDD.

Comment: I am from `C` background, where String (`char` array) and `long` occupies different memory footprint, say bytes. I want to store the date for per user purchase. For 10K users and per user 10 purchase it would be 0.1 million entries. That's why want to get some clarification. I might be wrong in Java world :)

Comment: You may be interested by reading this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown